# Pandas apply works on individual columns as expected, but not entire dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, apply

I have a dataframe that looks something like this:

```
pd.DataFrame({'state':['AL','AL'],'statefp':[1.0,1.0]})
  state  statefp
0    AL      1.0
1    AL      1.0
```

I want to turn the entire dataframe into type str and am using the `.apply` method. What I want to do is if the item is of type float, I want to store it as a string *integer*, and if it's already a string I want to lowercase it. I've tried this:

```
df.apply(lambda x: '{:.0f}'.format(x) if isinstance(x,float) else x.astype(str).str.lower())
```

Which outputs this (not what I wanted since `statefp` is stored as a string *float*):

```
  state statefp
0    al     1.0
1    al     1.0
```

However, when I use the same apply on just that column, it works fine:

```
>>>df.statefp.apply(lambda x: '{:.0f}'.format(x) if isinstance(x,float) else x.astype(str).str.lower())
0    1
1    1
```

Am I missing something about how `.apply` is working on the entire dataframe? I've also tried setting `axis='columns'` argument of  `.apply`, but that didn't work either.

Also, I am open to trying other code, not just `.apply`.

Answer (score 0):

Try using dtype instead:

```
df.apply(lambda x: x.astype(int).astype(str) if x.dtype==np.float else x.astype(str).str.lower())
```

Output:

```
  state  statefp
0    al        1
1    al        1

df.info()

<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 2 entries, 0 to 1
Data columns (total 2 columns):
state      2 non-null object
statefp    2 non-null object
dtypes: int32(1), object(1)
memory usage: 104.0+ bytes
```

Comment: Do you know if the `dtype` of `np.NaN` is `np.float`? There are some `NaN` in the `statefp` column and it's throwing this error: 'Cannot convert NA to integer', 'occurred at index statefp'

Comment: @LMc Yes, np.Nan is considered np.float. 'type(np.nan) == np.float' returns True